# How to extract protocol fields from pcap file in java

Tags: java, maven, smtp, protocols

i want to develop a simple software in java to extract the various protocol fields (SMTP) from PCAP file and display them at output, then,i will also have to analyze one or more functional or non-functional rules applicable for the selected protocol (example: constraints on one or more fields of a single
packet, constraints on fields of different packets, constraints on exchanges Etc.), For now i imported an pcap file in wireshark, and i have those information:

[image]

[image]

And now i want to do thise in java, can any one help me ?

Thank you!